# automate downloading aspx file from website using python

Tags: python, asp.net, web

I am trying to download aspx from a website using python.

url: https://ws2.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/0cdc8784-76a1-4cb2-9354-e549c34bc591FinancialData.aspx

Here my script

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

import pandas as pd

url = 'https://ws2.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/0cdc8784-76a1-4cb2-9354-e549c34bc591FinancialData.aspx'

urlretrieve (url, 'data.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';')

print(df.head())
```

it shows error.

Comment: Would be great if you could show the error

Comment: Also, that ASPX site returns HTML, not a readable CSV